# How to add a Receive Task using jBPM Eclipse Plugin

Tags: jbpm

I'm using jBPM 6.4.0

From eclipse I select New --> jBPM Process Diagram, then I try to design this very simple process:

```
StartProcess --> Receive Task --> End Event
```

Just by adding the components and connecting them I get this two validation errors on Receive Task:

1. Data Input MessageId () has no Data Type
2. Input Parameter MessageId () is uninitialized

This is normal as I still haven't configured the components.
The problem is, I can't figure out how to properly configure Receive Task to get rid of those validation errors.

Can someone help me understand how to properly configure the Receive Tasks' attributes ?